# shutil error using 'shutil.copy2' in python

Tags: python, windows, shutil

I'm looking to automate the retrieval of minecraft sounds via their hashes. To do this, I developed this piece of code:

```
list=songname.split("/", -1)
last=int(len(list)-1)
songnamebut=list[last]
listmenos=list[:-1]
destination="/".join(listmenos)
destination = f"son/{destination}"
destination=os.path.abspath(destination)
destination=f"{destination}\\{songnamebut}"
#os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(songname), exist_ok=True)
shutil.copy2(source, destination)
else:
pass
```

but I have an error which is the following:

```
Une exception s'est produite : FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Sunday\\All MC 1.18 Sounds\\son\\minecraft\\sounds\\ambient\\cave\\cave1.ogg'
  File "C:\Users\Sunday\All MC 1.18 Sounds\sounds_filter.py", line 28, in <module>
    shutil.copy2(source, destination)
```

I know my code looks weird, for example I created a variable "songnamebut" which only takes the name of the sound as "sounds.ogg" and separated the rest of the file path ("minecraft/sounds/") because, at first, I thought it couldn't create a folder with the same file name.

Thank you in advance!

As I said before, I first tried to change the folder name from "minecraft/sounds/sound.ogg" to "minecraft/sounds/" for the path and "sound.ogg" for the audio file but it didn't work. I also tried to pre-create all the folders by putting the shutil line as a comment and leaving only the os.makedirs. This worked but did not solve the problem.

Comment: Does the folder `C:\\Users\\Sunday\\All MC 1.18 Sounds\\son\\minecraft\\sounds\\ambient\\cave` exist? According to your comment, `os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(songname), exist_ok=True)` you were attempting to re-create the directory that contains your source file; maybe you wanted to use `destination` there instead of `songname`

Comment: @Talon yes, the directory already exist [image here](https://ibb.co/H2856vL). As a destination, I want my folder: "sound/minecraft/sounds/ambient/cave" (in this case) which according to the previous sentence, I have already created

Comment: In the screenshot, it seems like the `minecraft`-folder is directly below the `All MC 1.18 Sounds`, but in the code, there is a `son` folder between them. Is that layer missing maybe?

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. I will test that tomorrow !

Comment: @Talon Yes, that was it! I'm really sorry to have bothered you :)

Answer (score 0):

[Expanded from earlier comments]

The problem was to be that you have an extra `son` folder in the expected structure that was missing. Hence python couldn't find the destination folder and raised `FileNotFoundError`

`.../All MC 1.18 Sounds/son/minecraft/...`

vs
`.../All MC 1.18 Sounds/minecraft/...`

You can also simplify your code

```
path, _, last = songname.rpartition("/")
destination = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("son", path))
os.makedirs(destination, exist_ok=True)
shutil.copy2(source, destination)
```

Or when using pathlib:

```
import pathlib

file_dir = pathlib.Path(songname).parent
destination = pathlib.Path("son") / file_dir
destination.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
shutil.copy2(source, destination)
```